# Compositions preserving measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My question is based on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547882/prove-composition-is-a-measurable-function), which I summarize below. 
Claim: Let $(X, \textbf{X})$ be a measurable space, $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is **X**-measurable, $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.  Then $g \circ f$ is **X**-measurable. 
Pf: WTS $(g \circ f)^{-1}( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{X}$, $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  We have $(g \circ f)^{-1}( \alpha, \infty) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}( \alpha, \infty))$.  Now $g^{-1}( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{B}$ (is a Borel set), since g is cont.  Thus,  $f^{-1}(g^{-1}( \alpha, \infty)) \in \textbf{X}$, by [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802574/a-characterization-of-borel-measurability).

Looking at the Pf, it seems the only property of g being cont that we used was that $g^{-1}( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{B}$.  But if we weaken the hypothesis to g being **B**-measurable, then it seems that it's still true that $g^{-1}( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{B}$, again by the cited result and since $( \alpha, \infty) \in \textbf{B}$. 
Is this true?  Sorry I'm new to measure theory and unsure.  After all, if it was true, why bother with the special case that g is cont at all, since the proof technique would be no different?

Comment: Yes, requiring $g$ to be Borel measurable is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition of measurable functions where we use the same $\sigma$-algebras throughout, is measurable.

However, when speaking of *Lebesgue* measurable functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, the definition says that the inverse image of a set belonging to the *Borel* $\sigma$-algebra is a set that belongs to the *Lebesgue* $\sigma$-algebra. Hence for Lebesgue measurable $g$ it may happen that for some Borel set $E$, the set $g^{-1}(E)$ is Lebesgue, but not Borel. In that situation we are also no longer guaranteed that the $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(E))$ is Lebesgue.

Comment: Thx for the confirmation!  I have not yet learned about what the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is yet, but your remark motivates me to continue studying measure theory